# Checking if a URL is broken in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

This question has been posted on Stack before, but none so specific as to what I'm trying to understand.

The simplest way to check if a URL is corrrect to send a http Head request. But how do you use that to specify the URL ?

**I found this in a previous post :**

```
function UrlExists(url) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open('HEAD', url, false);
  http.send();
  return http.status!=404;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to run in firebug for a few reasons.

My apologies ahead of time for being daft.

Comment: Is Firebug giving any errors? Hope you are doing XHR on your own server and not to another site (re. the same origin policy). I copy pasted the code in firebug and it works fine and returns true/false

Comment: I'm typing it in as `urlExists("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'd recommend to use jQuery for correct cross-browser ajax requests:

```
function UrlExists(url, cb){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:      url,
        dataType: 'text',
        type:     'GET',
        complete:  function(xhr){
            if(typeof cb === 'function')
               cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
UrlExists('/path/script.pl', function(status){
    if(status === 200){
       // file was found
    }
    else if(status === 404){
       // 404 not found
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, but wouldn't you want to check for status codes other than 200 and 404? It could be a 500 or 304, etc

Comment: Is your if statement in your complete missing a `{}` ?

Comment: @Neil: indeed, it should be extended to check for more status codes. @Trip: no, you can do one statement without `{}`

Comment: Is this method still usable...? I'm getting a status 200 in firebug, but jQ status is 0 and reports a Cross Origin request error (my URL is in fact on another domain...but it's the 200 status I'm interested in, not any HTML)

Comment: What is `cb`?   .

Comment: `cb` is the callback function

Answer (score 17):

**Modern, cross and short way**

```
checkLink = async url => (await fetch(url)).ok
```

which is same of:

```
async checkLink(url) { return (await fetch(url)).ok }
```

which is same of:

```
async function checkLink(url) { return (await fetch(url)).ok }
```

which is same of:

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 /
> SeaMonkey 2.27), Blink 39.0, and Edge 13, synchronous requests on the
> main thread have been deprecated due to their negative impact on the
> user experience.

Cross solution (old, deprecated)

```
function UrlExists(url) {
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open('HEAD', url, false);
 http.send();
 return http.status==200;
}
```

Comment: Could you suggest anything if I try to check the 3rd party site and get the error: 
`Access to fetch at 'https://3rd.party.site' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy`?

Comment: @MegaCasper this is a common problem but there is no relation with the question. Mostly site needs explicity allow you to access his sites.