# Delete parent element and all children if img src broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing an Ajax query that pulls back a JSON array filled with ~50 urls to images. I then use a `forEach` on the array to produce a `<div>` nested with other `<div>`, with one of those `<div>` holding an `<img>` element in where I set the `src` equal to the current url in the `forEach` iteration.

The catch is that some of the urls are dead, and result in broken `<img>` elements ( you know, with the little images of a ripped file?). So what I do is, during the iterations, when I create my `<img>` element, I set the `onerror` attribute equal to `"$(this).closest('.gramDiv').remove()"`, which attempts to delete a certain `<img>` parent element and all of that parent's childrens. This works, but I feel like it's kinda hacky, and not best practice. Is there more standardized way of doing this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Ready");


        function adder(data,status){

            data.forEach((url,index)=>{
                let attrObj = {
                    src: url,
                    alt: 'photo ' + index, 
                    onerror: "$(this).closest('.targetDiv').remove()"
                };

                let img = $('<img>').attr(attrObj);

                let targetDiv = $('<div></div>').addClass('target');
                let picDiv = $('<div></div>').addClass('picDiv').append(img);

                let component = targetDiv.append(picDiv);

                $('#bodyDiv').append(component);
            })
        }  

        $.ajax({
            url:'https:/blahblahblah.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: adder,
            timeout: 3000,
            error: function(){ alert('error retrieving')}
        });


})
```

Comment: You could create `img` for only successfully loading images/

Comment: @Satpal How could I check for that?

Comment: `var img = new Image();img.src = url;
img.onload = function () { 
   //Append element 
};
`

Comment: Try this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915634/checking-if-a-url-is-broken-in-javascript)

Comment: @SabirAmeen this looks interesting, but is the Ajax pull in the example trying to pull back one piece of data, and checking the status? My issue is that my Ajax call pulls an entire array of urls, and some of them work while others done. Maybe I'm not understanding the code you linked, many of those keywords are new to me.

Comment: @MarkRomano you can check each url from the array using the UrlExists function in the link. If the file is found it returns statusCode 200 else 404

Comment: @SabirAmeen Ah ok I think I understand better now. I will try tomorrow and let you know thank you.

Comment: @SabirAmeen this worked Sabir thanks alot I'm going to answer my own question with your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this code

```
$("<img/>")
    .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
    .on('error', function() { console.log("error loading image"); })
    .attr("src", $(originalImage).attr("src"))
;
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SabirAmeen and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915634/checking-if-a-url-is-broken-in-javascript) for this answer.

Basically, within the `forEach` block, you want to run another ajax call on the URL of the current iteration, and retrieve it's `status`, which indicates whether it's working or broken. In my case, a working `status` is `200`, and anything else I consider broken.

I've simplified my code from above, but it still illustrates the point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Ready");


        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log("pressed");

        function adder(data,status){

            data = data.reduce(function(a,b){
                if(!a.includes(b)) a.push(b);
                return a;
            },[]);

            data.forEach((url,index)=>{             

                UrlExists(url, function(status){
                    if(status === 200){
                       // file was found
                       console.log('found:',status);
                       let img = $('<img>').attr('src',url);
                       $('body').append(img);
                    }
                    else {
                       // do nothing
                       console.log('not found:',status);
                    }
                });
            })
        }

        function UrlExists(url, cb){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:      url,
                dataType: 'text',
                type:     'GET',
                complete:  function(xhr){
                    if(typeof cb === 'function')
                       cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
                }
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:'https://yaddayadda.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            // success: adder,
            success: adder,
            //complete: remover,
            timeout: 3000,
            error: function(){ alert('error retrieving data fam')}
        });

})
```