# Check if url is working and if so do something

Tags: javascript

I found the following solution     [Checking if a URL is broken in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915634/checking-if-a-url-is-broken-in-javascript)

In the answer it says to use

```
checkLink = async url => (await fetch(url)).ok
```

to check if a url is available.

So let's assume I would like to display a message in case a url is working so I wrote:

```
let url = 'https://www.example.com/index.html';
if(checkLink = async url => (await fetch(url)).ok) {alert ("Hello world!");};
```

Unfortunately the above code always shows the alert message no matter if the url is available or not.
How can I use this code to test if a url is valid.

Answer (score 1):

With the function definition you gave

```
checkLink = async url => (await fetch(url)).ok
```

you would typically use this as follows.

```
async function doStuff() {
  let url = 'https://www.example.com/index.html';
  let doesLinkWork = await checkLink(url);
  if (doesLinkWork) {
    alert("it works");
  } else {
    alert("it doesn't work");
  }
}
```

and then call `doStuff` from the console or from somewhere else in your code. (Obviously that function name is just an example - you should call it something more appropriate to what you actually want it to do!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use an input field or something of the sorts, you can use checkValidity().
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function validation() {
        const inp = document.getElementById("url");
        const p = document.getElementById("text");
        if(!inp.checkValidity()){
          p.innerText = inp.validationMessage;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <form>
      <input id="url" type="url" placeholder="URL Here">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validation()">
    </form>
    <p id="text"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```